# How can I unit-test the presence of specific file contents, through an interface?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, interfaces

I am currently trying to test a file manager class. This class is responsible for keeping track of how long the file is good for. The file will have a date written into it that denotes when it was generated as well as the duration of how long the file is good for. Consumers of my interface will be agnostic to these details. The interface looks like:

```
public interface IFileManager
{
    bool GenerateFile(string location);
    bool DeleteFile(string location);
    bool IsFileValid(string location);
    bool Update(string customerID, string location);
}
```

I am concerned with how to test one of these methods, specifically `IsValid(string location)`. Part of the implementation I am planning on for `IsValid` will be to check whether the file has expired, as well as the file not just containing garbage.

Okay, so here is my conundrum. I always write my unit tests in a separate project, where they only have a reference to an interface library. That is, I test everything through an interface so my unit tests will only know about `IFileManager`. So from a high-level interface, how do I test a specific implementation of an "expired" or "garbage" file?

My interface does not allow for a client of said interface to create a file that's already expired. And that makes sense to me! On top of that, I don't want to add in functionality to my interface just to be able to test! My thoughts about how can I test this, give me a code smell.

Comment: The same way you unit test anything, with __Mocks!__

Comment: @esoterik Would you test an embedded system like that?

Comment: Mocks or simulation for unit-tests certainly; (n.b. not the only kind of tests)

Comment: @esoterik I saw you were active on EE, just figured I'd poke you on that one :)

Comment: @Snoop I’ve created thin abstractions around Linux syscalls so they could be mocked. I’ve created mock registers for mcu drivers. So... yes. Yes I do test embedded systems that way.

Comment: @RubberDuck I need to do better testing for my embedded systems.

Comment: @Snoop you may be interested in [this blog of mine then](https://christopherjmcclellan.wordpress.com/2018/02/16/test-driving-arduino/). I lead a workshop a few months ago  on TDDing a LED driver.

Comment: @RubberDuck Awesome, have to check that out at home... and, it kind of sounds like we do similar work.

Comment: Awesome! If you’re already doing that and want to up your testing, maybe take a look at [LOOP](https://loopbypillar.com/)

Comment: @RubberDuck Actually... that might be pretty good because a lot of the time I am doing work writing APIs to control embedded hardware. Right now I use physical products to test my APIs, in a sort of classical TDD manner.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79191/discussion-between-snoop-and-rubberduck).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My thoughts about how can I test this, give me a code smell.

This API is encapsulating a side effect.  And that's fine -- most of your code doesn't need to know the details.  But for unit testing, you probably need a way to replace the side effect with a test double.

You're implementation is probably using a small number of calls to some File library to do the actual work.  So the idea is to have an interface that wraps those calls, and pass an instance of that interface in to get the `IFileManager` you want.

```
interface FilePrimitives { ... }

IFileManager fileManager(FilePrimitives filePrimitives) { ... }
```

The is basically the "Strategy" pattern at work.

In your production code, you initialize the FileManager using an implementation of FilePrimitives that makes actual library calls. The primitives are effectively part of the "imperative shell", where your code interacts with the outside world.

Key point: one of your constraints in implementing the primitives is that they should be too simple to break.

When you are testing, instead of using the "real" primitives, you use a test double, and control the responses from the test.

So if you want to test a garbage file, you set up your test double so that it reacts *as if* there really is a garbage file, and then use that to initialize the rest of your system.

Your test is really two pieces -- it is both a use case (exercising the API) validator, but it is also a [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/).

> So you are saying to abstract the file library and then inject a mock version of it that always reports that a file is expired?

Yes, although I would spell it somewhat differently: we're taking the [decision](https://blog.acolyer.org/2016/09/05/on-the-criteria-to-be-used-in-decomposing-systems-into-modules/) to use this file library, and placing a module boundary around that decision, so that we can change that decision in the test harness.

Comment: This is a good idea. Could I go so far as to letting the test library use the `FilePrimitives` interface, without breaking any conventions?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "use"; the motivation is to allow you to replace one strategy with another -- meaning that could be a strategy that you _implement_ in your test library.

Comment: Okay, I guess I need to re-read this.

Comment: So you are saying to abstract the file library and then inject a mock version of it that always reports that a file is expired?

Comment: This is a spot on answer. The key is that actually reading/writing the files is a separate responsibility to determining is the content is valid, if its expired etc. So separate the concerns and inject the file read/writer into the `FileManager`. That way, you can easily test the latter with a mock of the former, allowing your tests to control expiration, content validity etc.

Comment: @DavidArno Similar to this answer, is the most recent answer by kevincline... It seems like their perspective is that getting the time is also a separate responsibility... and so that could be injected as well.

Comment: Yes.  Most side effects should have very small boundaries around an idiot proof implementation.  Reads, writes, time, random numbers, environment variables....

Comment: I'm kind of getting lost on *side effects*. What does that mean exactly?

Comment: Coarsely: anything that's not completely under your control; the parts of the system that can change without your process touching them.  Think file system: your process is one of any number of collaborators sharing it, and even though you just checked that a file exists, somebody else can remove the file / change the permissions / unmount the volume when you go to read from it.

Comment: @VoiceOfUnreason Okay, kind of what I figured. But it almost sounded like you were defining a side effect as some sort of feature or something... which I guess it sort of is, in that it does have test cases associated it.

Comment: @Snoop, absolutely you should inject the time too. "Side effects" means changes to state beyond your the scope of a piece of code. So a method that sets or reads a mutable property has side effects but they are confined to the object instance. If it reads or changes a mutable global variable, it has side effects that affect the entire application scope. If it eg reads or writes to files, the current time, a database etc, then those side effects have a scope beyond the app or test run. The wider the scope the more easily the test can fail randomly and unexpectedly.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of calling some static system method to get the current time, inject the time source as a dependency. Then you mock the time source to simulate time passing. Here's some Java code:

```
class FileManager {
    private Supplier<Instant> timeSource;

    public FileManager() {
        this(() -> Instant.now());
    }

    public FileManager(Supplier<Instant> timeSource) { 
         this.timeSource = timeSource;
    }

    public GenerateFile() {
        Instant currentTime = timeSource.get();
        ...
    }
    public IsFileValid() {
      Instant currentTime = timeSource.get();
      ...
    }
}
```

Now use your favorite mocking library to create a mock time source:

```
public class FileManagerTest() {
     public void WHEN_file_expired_THEN_not_valid() {
          when(mockTimeSource.get()).thenReturn(someTime)
                                   .thenReturn(aLaterTime);
          FileManager manager = new FileManager(mockTimeSource);
          GenerateFile(...);
          assert(! IsFileValid(...));
     }
}
```

Comment: If I understand this correctly... is it similar to what @VoiceOfUnreason is saying?

Comment: @Snoop: Maybe, I'm not really sure. I code for testability and refactor as needed.

Answer (score 3):

If you're testing the implementation of the interface, then you'll have a concrete class, implementing the interface, and the unit tests will be able to access this class.

If you're testing the classes which have `IFileManager` as a dependency, then create a stub/mock which implements `IFileManager` and, when calling `IsFileValid` returns always `true` or always `false` or a value which will be configured in every test.

Comment: Okay, but I care about the process of... *is the file expired*. How would I be testing that?

Comment: It depends entirely on the concrete implementation. I suppose that there is a specific algorithm which determines whether the file is expired. By studying the algorithm, you may find what should be tested and how.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that you have knowledge of the implementing class that you are trying to test or at least all the information on how it is implemented.

In your test class you need only instantiate the implementing class:

```
IFileManager myInstance = new implementingClass();
// prepare the file to test
...
bool result = myInstance.IsFileValid(@"SomeLocation");
// process result
...
```

If you wanted to get really generic, you can use reflection to get the class (or classes) that implement the interface and use Invoke to call the class' constructor.

```
// Loop through the .DLLs where the implementation is kept.
// Test that it contains the IFileManager interface
...
ConstructorInfo ci = myModule.GetType().GetInterface(@"IFileManager").GetConstructorInfo(new Type[0]);
// The above needs error handling and validation, an exercise to do.
// Instantiate the class that implemented IFileManager
IFileManager ifm = ci.Invoke(new Object[0]);
// Now perform you tests by calling the methods:
ifm.IsFileValid(@"SomeFile");
...
```

That is a gross simplification of the steps but the key idea is there.
Use reflection to get all the DLLs that implement your interface then test them by instantiating each class and testing the implementation.

Comment: Are you suggesting that they perform a round trip-test with canned/generated/etc. data?

Comment: Yes, that is the usual, however modifying an existing file would work as well. Usually I have test data I create/use that will test all the conditions: Good; Fail and Edge. In this way any new implementation or update can be regression tested to demonstrate it works/doesn't break old code.

Answer (score 0):

> I always write my unit tests in a separate project, where they only have a reference to an interface library. That is, I test everything through an interface so my unit tests will only know about IFileManager

I am repeating at least one answer, but I'd like to additionally emphisize, that this quoted approach does not seem right to me. You can use abstracting a dependency when unit-testing the depended code, thst is: you could inject mock implememtation of IFileManager to test a code which uses FileManager. But to test the FileManager itself you test the concrete class. Limiting it to interface is not yet bad as is, it just does not bring any benefit. And when test needs to use some private details, like to mock the time function, it starts being an obstacle.

Comment: Hmm... nobody else has really said anything about that so far.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that on the interface level, a unit test of IsFileValid probably doesn't make sense.

Is the fact that file validity is determined by the current time compared to a time range in the file a defined part of the interface?  Is it impossible to have different implementations of IFileManager that determine validity by some other metric, such as version number?

If so, then fine, you can test for that (although at the point that implementation details are defined to that extent you're losing some of the point of having an interface).  If not, then what exactly would a unit test of IsFileValid be testing?  That it returns either true or false?  Because either one could be a valid output for a given file in some possible implementation.

If for a specific concrete implementation, file validity is by definition based on a time range as stated above, then unit test that concrete implementation.